# RDS Postgresql CPU usage 100% with unknown connections "others"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using Multi AZ RDS Postgresql db.m4.2xlarge instance. For a couple of days my instance is experiencing 100% CPU utilization. I have enabled performance insight and it is showing normal AAS for my queries along with the *others* connections, which are not connected with any SQL or HOST so can't be traced. Screen shot is below:

[image]

Comment: What does pg_stat_activity show?

Comment: it shows all those connections which are not part of others.